# shape error while concating columns after Principal Analysis in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, pca

I am applying PCA in my csv data.
After normalization, seems PCA is working.
I want to plot projection by making 4 components. but I am stuck with this error :

```
 type         x         y  ...             fx             fy   fz
0     0 -0.639547 -1.013450  ... -8.600000e-231 -1.390000e-230  0.0
0     1 -0.497006 -2.311890  ...   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00  0.0
1     0  0.154376 -0.873189  ...  1.150000e-228 -1.480000e-226  0.0
1     1 -0.342055 -2.179370  ...   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00  0.0
2     0  0.312719 -0.872756  ... -2.370000e-221  2.420000e-221  0.0

[5 rows x 10 columns]

(1047064, 10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-0b631a51ce61> in <module>()
     33 
     34 
---> 35 finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, df[['type']]], axis = 1)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in _verify_integrity(self)
    327         for block in self.blocks:
    328             if block.shape[1:] != mgr_shape[1:]:
--> 329                 raise construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
    330         if len(self.items) != tot_items:
    331             raise AssertionError(

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2617660, 5), indices imply (1570596, 5)
```

This is my code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


df1=pd.read_csv('./data/1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('./data/2.csv')
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).sort_index()
print(df.head())
print(df.shape)

features = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'vx', 'vy', 'vz', 'fx', 'fy', 'fz']
# Separating out the features
x = df.loc[:, features].values
# Separating out the target
y = df.loc[:,['type']].values
# Standardizing the features
x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)

pca = PCA(n_components=4)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
             , columns = ['pcc1','pcc2','pcc3', 'pcc4'])


finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, df[['type']]], axis = 1)
```

I guess I am getting error while concat my components and df['type'].

Can I get idea to get rid of this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index in `df` is not the same as in `principalDf`. We have (using a short version of your data)

```
df.index
Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], dtype='int64')
```

and

```
principalDf.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)
```

Hence `concat` is getting confused. You can fix this by resetting the index early on:

```
...
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).sort_index().reset_index() # note reset_index() added
...
```

Comment: It works. I also realized that there are many 'NAN' values in df2 after concat. I gues this happens because of different shape of data.